# array of objects vs array of delimited array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to create an array of searchable items but I'm not sure whether I should create an array of custom objects or just an array of delimited strings. Can someone give me some advice on which is the better way. Below is an example:

```
var Arr = [  "Arts Tower|ArtsTower.htm|104", 
             "Arts Tower|ArtsTower.htm|1203", 
             "Arts Tower|ArtsTower.htm|Arts Tower"
          ];

var searchTerm = "tow"

var ArrResults = jQuery.grep(Arr, function(value, index){
 return (value.split("|")[2].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) != -1);
});
```

or

```
function Item(name, url, str){
  this.name = name;
  this.url = url;
  this.str= str;
}

var Arr = new Array();
Arr.push(new Item("Arts Tower", "ArtsTower.htm", "104"));
Arr.push(new Item("Arts Tower", "ArtsTower.htm", "1203"));
Arr.push(new Item("Arts Tower", "ArtsTower.htm", "Arts Tower"));

var searchTerm = "tow"

var ArrResults = jQuery.grep(Arr, function(value, index){
  return (value.str.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) != -1);
});
```

I need to search the array and return back any matches. Which would perform better?

Comment: As far as I can see, performance is almost the same - only with millions of items you'll notice any difference. Performance aside, the second approach is more elegant so I suggest to go with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Array and Object constructors and pushing items to an array is an overkill (and unnecessary for static data like yours).

Using proprietary encoding (using pipe delimiters) that needs additional processing to parse is also not favorable.

I would go with an array of objects in literal form:

```
var Arr = [
    { name: "Arts Tower", url: "ArtsTower.htm", str: "104" },
    { name: "Arts Tower", url: "ArtsTower.htm", str: "1203" },
    { name: "Arts Tower", url: "ArtsTower.htm", str: "Arts Tower" }
];
```

This also brings you closer to a point where you would want to load the data via XHR ($.ajax).

Comment: ok sounds good.  Im getting the data to load from elements on the page.  How would i load the values into the array of object literals?

Comment: Double quoting the property names (so that it becomes valid JSON) and stuffing the bit after the `var Arr =` into a file on your server and then fetching it via `$.getJSON()` should be enough.

Comment: @Richard - "Dynamically" from where?

Comment: its all client side.  The values are coming from the area elements of an image map

Comment: +1 I'd go for an array of objects too. Object propery access is going to be quicker than string manipulation.

Comment: @Richard, I would have to see the source elements to be able to answer that.

Comment: Thanks @Ates i think ive got it now.  Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which one of your suggestions are faster, but I would personally use the second example.  This is because of later usage of your ArrResults arary. If that array contains strings, you would have to split it every time you'd use one of your results, like this: `ArrResults[0].split('|')[0]`  instead of just `ArrResults[0].name`